# Display div, if keyword is present AND exclusion keyword is not present

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a successful keyword argument working in jQuery using

```
var text = $("#pbtitle").text();

    options.forEach( function( element ) {
    if ( text.indexOf( element ) != -1 ) {    // if its NOT -1 (-1 = not found)
      $('.install_option').css('display','block'); // then we found it .. do your magic
    }
});
```

However, I know wish to incorporate some negative/exclusion keywords. But struggling to get it working fully:

```
<h1 id="pbtitle"><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>

<div class="install_option" style="display:none; margin-bottom: 25px; overflow:hidden; box-sizing:border-box;">              
    <p>Take upgrade option</p>
</div>

var options = ['Adult Membership','Jnr Membership','Family Ticket'];
var exclusions = ['2016','Expired,'Void'];
var text = $("#pbtitle").text();

    options.forEach( function( element ) {
    if ( text.indexOf( element ) != -1 )     // if its NOT -1 (-1 = not found)

    &&

    exclusions.forEach( function( elements ) {
    if ( text.indexOf( elements ) == 1 ) {    // if its NOT -1 (-1 = not found)


      $('.install_option').css('display','block'); // then we found it .. do your magic   
    }
    else
    {
      $('.install_option').css('display','none'); 
    }
});
```

"So, if an option keyword *is* matched AND an exclusion keyword *is not* present. Display the 'install option' div. If not, keep the div hidden"

Example Outcomes

- Adult Membership - Displays "Install Option" DIV
- Jnr Membership 2017 - Displays "Install Option" DIV
- Jnr Membership 2016 -  DOES NOT DISPLAY "Install Option" DIV
- Family Ticket Expired - DOES NOT DISPLAY "Install Option" DIV
- Family Pass - DOES NOT DISPLAY "Install Option" DIV

Comment: for both functions the comment is the same: if its NOT -1 (-1 = not found), is that intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out the other functions that Arrays provide. In this case `forEach` ain't what you are looking for:

And especially you don't want to change the `display` value inside the loop, because it has an awful performance and the final result depends on the last iteration only.

```
var options = ['Adult Membership','Jnr Membership','Family Ticket'];
var exclusions = ['2016','Expired','Void'];
var text = $("#pbtitle").text();

var inText = word => text.includes(word);
$('.install_option').css('display', options.some(inText) && !exclusions.some(inText)? 'block': 'none');
```

Comment: Looks more compact this block. But not working yet https://jsfiddle.net/4j41sv0h/

Comment: Sorry, try this (with jQuery!) https://plnkr.co/edit/CoAkHOKuFnWaOi2noG2s?p=preview

Comment: my bad, it's `String#includes()` not contains, fixed that. And you have to load jquery if you want to use it: https://jsfiddle.net/4j41sv0h/1/

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use `&&` in a strange way. It should work as follows:

```
expression1 && expression2 && ... && expreesionN
```

Each expression is evaluated to `true` or `false` becuase all the values in JS are either boolean or boolean-like (that is, while convertion they become either `true` or `false`).

In your case what takes place is:

```
if ( text.indexOf( element ) != -1 )     // if its NOT -1 (-1 = not found)

    &&

    exclusions.forEach( function( elements ) {
```

But what does `exclusions.forEach` return?

Instead of this I'd recommend to declare two variables indicating if any keword is found in the text and any exlucsion word is in the text, and then check whatever you want:

```
var hasKeywords = false,
    hasExclusions = false;

options.forEach(function(singleOption){
    // if at least (!) one option is found in the text you can definitely state the text contains keyword
    if (text.indexOf(singleOption) >= 0) { hasKeywords = true}
});

exclusions.forEach(function(element){
    // if at least on exclusion is found in the text you can say for sure that forbidden words are present
    if (text.indexOf(element) >= 0) { hasExclusions = true}
});

if (hasKeywords && !hasExclusions) {
    // do whatever you want
}
```

in this way you check for both conditions and explicitly check for them rather than turn everything into makaronee code. The variable names are pretty clear and easy to be used in boolean expressions

Comment: @merch89 first, place `<script src="script.js"></script>` after (!) the page loads. Because the text which you're trying to get by `text()` jQuery function is just empty!

Comment: @merch89 then I'd recommend to use `console.log` to track what variable stores what value. I've updated the files content, have a look: https://plnkr.co/edit/cwlKYiUYeQoKxc3tkiuX?p=preview

Comment: @merch89 do smth from your side before just saying "Not working"

Comment: @merch89 open your console to see the output